# Table of contents like

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a list of "mini-paragraph" for example:

```
id:Object1:
Title:xxxx
Author:yyyy
ecc..

id:Object2:
Title:xxxx
Author:yyyy
ecc..
```

I don't need to put the id in tableofcontent but i need to create a list, like tableofcontent, of all id, for example:

```
Obect1: page 3 (with link to the page)
Object2: page.
```

If I only put a `\label` tag then I need to insert all `\ref` tags but I need something to do it automatically. Any suggestion?

**EDIT1:**
An example is this:

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\begin{list}{}{\textbf{Modifica Tag}}
    \item {\textbf{Identificativo:}} \texttt{RF-ADMIN-Tag.edit}
    \item {\textbf{Descrizione:}} L’amministratore vuole modificare il nome di un tag esistente. Accede quindi alla sezione relativa ai tag negli strumenti di amministrazione, seleziona il tag di interesse e ne modifica il nome. 
Il sistema visualizza la lista dei tag aggiornata.
    \item {\textbf{Precondizioni:}} Login come utente amministratore. Questo stato è verificato in seguito all’applicazione del requisito RF-Login.
    \item {\textbf{Input:}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nome tag
        \item tag da modificare
    \end{itemize}
    \item {\textbf{Output:}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Lista dei tag aggiornata in ordine alfabetico
    \end{itemize}
    \item {\textbf{Priorità:}} Alta
\end{list}
```

In the second line I have `\textbf{Modifica Tag}`, the "id" of object is "Modifica Tag" (the title of the list). I need to get this "id" from all object and put in a table of contents like.

My document class definition is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For images
\usepackage{multirow} % For multirow tables
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Per le classi di numeri
\usepackage{amsmath} % Per le frazioni
\usepackage{hyperref} % Per i link
\usepackage{eurosym} % Per usare il simbolo dell'euro
\usepackage{acronym} % Per gli acronimi

\graphicspath{{./immagini/}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\refname{Riferimenti}} % con pacchetti lingue

\begin{document}
[..]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide a MWE for folks to start from?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Without some more information as to how the "id:Object" objects are defined and created, it's going to be very difficult to provide concrete suggestions regarding how a list of these objects could be generated. Please post a Minimum Working Example -- starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` -- that shows how these objects are created. Some more information about how you would like the list of these objects to look like would also be useful.

Comment: I have add more information.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using the kernel's  `\@starttoc` to generate the list (the associated auxiliary file will have extension `.loi`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofidname{List of IDs}
\newcommand\listofids{
  \section*{\listofidname}
  \@starttoc{loi}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\myid[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{loi}{section}{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\listofids

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\begin{list}{}{\myid{Modifica Tag}}
    \item {\textbf{Identificativo:}} \texttt{RF-ADMIN-Tag.edit}
    \item {\textbf{Descrizione:}} L’amministratore vuole modificare il nome di un tag esistente. Accede quindi alla sezione relativa ai tag negli strumenti di amministrazione, seleziona il tag di interesse e ne modifica il nome. 
Il sistema visualizza la lista dei tag aggiornata.
    \item {\textbf{Precondizioni:}} Login come utente amministratore. Questo stato è verificato in seguito all’applicazione del requisito RF-Login.
    \item {\textbf{Input:}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nome tag
        \item tag da modificare
    \end{itemize}
    \item {\textbf{Output:}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Lista dei tag aggiornata in ordine alfabetico
    \end{itemize}
    \item {\textbf{Priorità:}} Alta
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\listofids` you generate the list eghich is built in a similar fashion as a table of contents. The name for this list can be changed appropriately redefining `\listofidname`. You use the command `\myid` to typeset its argument to the document and produce the entry in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Another option. This will make a list of the `"id"`'s, which will also include `Part` information. You can modify the code to also include `Section` information (this is indicated in the comments).

The method defines a counter `id`, and after `\myid` you can then optionnally use a `\label` command to benefit from the `\label/\ref` mechanism of `LaTeX2e`.

Output:

> [image: list of IDs]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoc}
\newcounter{id}
% we will add "id" lines to the .toc file, but don't want them to appear in the
% standard toc file:
\etocsetlevel{id}{6}

\newcommand\listofidname{List of IDs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofids{%
  \begingroup
   \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\listofidname}
   \etocsetlevel {id}{1}
% with current etoc (1.07k) the following needs to be done explicitely for the
% table of contents done in "compatibility mode". For TOCs using specific
% styles as set-up by  the user via \etocsetstyle, there would be no need and no
% use to do that.
   \let\l@id\l@section % print id entries as one does for section TOC entries
%
   \etocsetnexttocdepth {id}   % (no subsections etc...)
   \etocsetlevel {section}{6}  % do not print sections, only parts and "id"
                               % entries 
% % ALTERNATIVE: print id's as subsections
% \let\l@id\l@subsection
% \etocsetlevel{id}{2}
% \etocsetlevel{subsection}{6}
% \etocsetnexttocdepth{id}
   \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\myid[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{id}%
  \etoctoccontentsline {id}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

% \tableofcontents % this will be standard one

\listofids


\part{First part}

\section{A section}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\begin{list}{}{\myid{Modifica Tag}}
    \item {\textbf{Identificativo:}} \texttt{RF-ADMIN-Tag.edit}
    \item {\textbf{Descrizione:}} L’amministratore vuole modificare il nome di un tag esistente. Accede quindi alla sezione relativa ai tag negli strumenti di amministrazione, seleziona il tag di interesse e ne modifica il nome. 
Il sistema visualizza la lista dei tag aggiornata.
    \item {\textbf{Precondizioni:}} Login come utente amministratore. Questo stato è verificato in seguito all’applicazione del requisito RF-Login.
    \item {\textbf{Input:}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nome tag
        \item tag da modificare
    \end{itemize}
    \item {\textbf{Output:}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Lista dei tag aggiornata in ordine alfabetico
    \end{itemize}
    \item {\textbf{Priorità:}} Alta
\end{list}

\part{Second part}

\section{A section in the second part}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\begin{list}{}{\myid{Modifica Tag Due}}
    \item {\textbf{Identificativo:}} \texttt{RF-ADMIN-Tag.edit}
    \item {\textbf{Descrizione:}} L’amministratore vuole modificare il nome di un tag esistente. Accede quindi alla sezione relativa ai tag negli strumenti di amministrazione, seleziona il tag di interesse e ne modifica il nome. 
Il sistema visualizza la lista dei tag aggiornata.
    \item {\textbf{Precondizioni:}} Login come utente amministratore. Questo stato è verificato in seguito all’applicazione del requisito RF-Login.
    \item {\textbf{Input:}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nome tag
        \item tag da modificare
    \end{itemize}
    \item {\textbf{Output:}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Lista dei tag aggiornata in ordine alfabetico
    \end{itemize}
    \item {\textbf{Priorità:}} Alta
\end{list}

\end{document}
```